# Organizing complex map data structure

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I write in Qt C++ and I want to create some object (type of *ISaveFile*) that will save my data to file after some delay. And also I want my data to be saved in structured order. For example

```
// After some user changes

file->beginGroup("Cool settings");
file->setValue("setpoint_1", value_1);
file->setValue("setpoint_2", value_2);

file->beginGroup("Nested setpoint_3");
file->setValue("par_1", value_1);
file->setValue("par_2", value_2);
file->endGroup(); // Nested setpoint_3

file->endGroup(); // Cool settings
```

(where method **setValue** receives *QVariant* as value type)

And after that the **file** object will save it automatically after some time interval.

And the **question** is: how to organize storing data inside file to reduce all that nested map complexity.

One of the quickest solutions - If I would like to create JsonSaveFile a descendant of *ISaveFile*,  the owner of the **file object** can fill *QJsonObject* directly, and then pass it to **file**'s map, and no problem. But it lacks of oop, and what if I will want to write *XmlSaveFile* or others in future.

Comment: Serializing **any** data results in flat data, hence the term "serialization". Nesting complexity is irrelevant, you iterate and serialize. Stuff like JSON or XML is still a flat file, visual structuring is entirely optional and only exists for the purpose of human readability.

Comment: I don't understand it how to do it with serialization of flat data. The idea of my ISaveFile that I can add data to it from different places of code and it will delayedly save it. Serialization, as I know, means that I write all data that wll be saved, not just part of it.

Comment: BTW I think I found the solution. Can't insert readable code into the comment. But idea is  to create class Map which will have one map for own values and one map for nested maps, and variable for storing the current map (pointer to the active nested map or nullptr if this map is current). Smth like this in private section: QMap<QString, QVariant> values;  QMap<QString, Map *> maps;    Map *currentMap = nullptr; Then in each method of the class we check if currentMap is not null, then call his analogous method, else process it by ourselfes.

Comment: If you have a deep data tree structure and you don't want to rewrite everything on small changes, you can designate specific nodes of the tree to write to individual files. This only makes sense if your structure is very big tho.

Comment: Thank you for advice. No I have relatively small structure. Also if I will have to write big one I can separate the data saving into several more small parts (different parts of the data write to different save files) to not to deal with nodes' savings.

Comment: Depending on your needs, be aware that Qt's container can be serialized in a [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#details) with no code at all but a `dataStream << myContainer`, whatever the complexity of nested containers you have (as long as each basic type is accepted by QDataStream).

Comment: @ymoreau Thank you for your tip.